# One button random sounds

Tags: android

I have one simple app with just one button. When i push it, it will play one sound(btn001). What i would like it to do is play a random sounds from raw folder. I have there 47 soundfiles named btn001 to btn047. Is there any simple way to modify my code to make it work.
I know there are alot same questions on the web. I've tryed all of them i have found. I'ts so frustrating but have'nt got it to work.
Here is my code:

```
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer cheer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.btn001);

        pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cheer.start();
            ;
            };}

        );
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list where you add all your sounds and then play a random sound from that list.
You could get a random index by `(int)(Math.random()*47)`

Comment: After alot of trial and error still not mutch luck, but i got this far that every time app starts it plays different sound and plays same sound on every buttonclick. To play different random sound i have to restart that app.

Comment: @Türbel Can you please update your question with the new code? This should be easy to fix

Comment: So looks like it is not so easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! Now the code works. I post the final code so that if anyone else needs something like that. It needs to change only their APPNAME and the names of soundfiles.

```
package com.example.APPNAME;

import java.util.Random;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    final int[] btns = new int[] {R.raw.btn001, R.raw.btn002, R.raw.btn003, R.raw.btn004, R.raw.btn005, R.raw.btn006,
            R.raw.btn007, R.raw.btn008, R.raw.btn009, R.raw.btn010, R.raw.btn011, R.raw.btn012, R.raw.btn013,
            R.raw.btn014, R.raw.btn015, R.raw.btn016, R.raw.btn017, R.raw.btn018, R.raw.btn019, R.raw.btn020,
            R.raw.btn021, R.raw.btn022, R.raw.btn023, R.raw.btn024, R.raw.btn025, R.raw.btn026, R.raw.btn027,
            R.raw.btn028, R.raw.btn029, R.raw.btn030, R.raw.btn031, R.raw.btn032, R.raw.btn033, R.raw.btn034,
            R.raw.btn035, R.raw.btn036, R.raw.btn037, R.raw.btn038, R.raw.btn039, R.raw.btn040, R.raw.btn041,
            R.raw.btn042, R.raw.btn043, R.raw.btn044, R.raw.btn045, R.raw.btn046, R.raw.btn047,     
    };
    private Random rnd = new Random();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(btns.length);
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, btns[sndToPlay] );
            mp.start();
        ;
        };}
    );
        }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple app with one button that should play random sound (btn001 - btn047) on every click. Right now it plays only one randomly selected sound every click. And to play some other sound i have to close and start the app again.

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// MediaPlayer player;
private Random rnd = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // player = new MediaPlayer;
    Button sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    // Random r = new Random();
    // int x = r.nextInt(1);

    final int[] btns = new int[] {R.raw.btn001, R.raw.btn002, R.raw.btn003, R.raw.btn004, R.raw.btn005, R.raw.btn006,
            R.raw.btn007, R.raw.btn008, R.raw.btn009, R.raw.btn010, R.raw.btn011, R.raw.btn012, R.raw.btn013,
            R.raw.btn014, R.raw.btn015, R.raw.btn016, R.raw.btn017, R.raw.btn018, R.raw.btn019, R.raw.btn020,
            R.raw.btn021, R.raw.btn022, R.raw.btn023, R.raw.btn024, R.raw.btn025, R.raw.btn026, R.raw.btn027,
            R.raw.btn028, R.raw.btn029, R.raw.btn030, R.raw.btn031, R.raw.btn032, R.raw.btn033, R.raw.btn034,
            R.raw.btn035, R.raw.btn036, R.raw.btn037, R.raw.btn038, R.raw.btn039, R.raw.btn040, R.raw.btn041,
            R.raw.btn042, R.raw.btn043, R.raw.btn044, R.raw.btn045, R.raw.btn046, R.raw.btn047,     
    };
    // new int alfa = btns;

    // private Random rnd = new btns;

    int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(btns.length);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, btns[sndToPlay] );
  // mp.seekTo(0);
  // mp.start();  

    // final MediaPlayer cheer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.btn001);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        ;
        };}

    );
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Put the two lines int `sndToPlay = ...` and `MediaPlayer mp = ...` into the onClick-Event